# How to fix TypeError: in setindex! in DifferentialEquations.jl

Tags: julia, typeerror, ode, differential-equations

Recently, I got started with Julia's (v1.0.3) `DifferentialEquations.jl` package. I tried solving a simple ODE system, with the same structure as my real model, but much smaller.
Depending on the solver which I use, the example either solves or throws an error. Consider this MWE, a Chemical Engineering model of a consecutive / parallel reaction in a CSTR:

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots

# Modeling a consecutive / parallel reaction in a CSTR
# A --> 2B --> C, C --> 2B, B --> D
# PETERSEN-Matrix
#   No.     A       B       C       D       Rate
#   1      -1       2                       k1*A
#   2              -2       1               k2*B*B
#   3               2      -1               k3*C
#   4              -1               1       k4*B

function fpr(dx, x, params, t)
    k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4, q_in, V_liq, A_in, B_in, C_in, D_in = params
    # Rate equations
    rate = Array{Float64}(undef, 4)
    rate[1] = k_1*x[1]
    rate[2] = k_2*x[2]*x[2]
    rate[3] = k_3*x[3]
    rate[4] = k_4*x[2]

    dx[1] = -rate[1] + q_in/V_liq*(A_in - x[1])
    dx[2] = 2*rate[1] - 2*rate[2] + 2*rate[3] - rate[4] + q_in/V_liq*(B_in - x[2])
    dx[3] = rate[2] - rate[3] + q_in/V_liq*(C_in - x[3])
    dx[4] = rate[4] + q_in/V_liq*(D_in - x[4])
end 

u0 = [1.5, 0.1, 0, 0]
params = [1.0, 1.5, 0.75, 0.15, 3, 15, 0.5, 0, 0, 0]
tspan = (0.0, 15.0)
prob = ODEProblem(fpr, u0, tspan, params)
sol = solve(prob)
plot(sol)
```

This works perfectly.
However, if a choose a different solver, say `Rosenbrock23()` or `Rodas4()`, the ODE is not solved and I get the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: TypeError: in setindex!, in typeassert, expected Float64,
got ForwardDiff.Dual{Nothing,Float64,4}
```

I won't paste the whole stacktrace here, since it is very long, but you can easily reproduce this by changing `sol = solve(prob)` into `sol = solve(prob, Rosenbrock23())`. It seems to me that the error occurs when the solver tries to derive Jacobians, but I have no clue why. And why does the default solver work, but others don't?

Please, could anyone tell me why this error occurs and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Should you not have `rate[2]=k_2*x[2]*x[2]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic differentiation works by passing `Dual` types through your function, instead of the floats you would normally use it with.  So the problem arises because you fix the internal value `rate` to be of type `Vector{Float64}` (see the third point [here](http://www.juliadiff.org/ForwardDiff.jl/stable/user/limitations.html), and [this advice](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/basics/faq.html#I-get-Dual-number-errors-when-I-solve-my-ODE-with-Rosenbrock-or-SDIRK-methods...?-1)).  Fortunately, that's easy to fix (and even better looking, IMHO):

```
julia> function fpr(dx, x, params, t)
           k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4, q_in, V_liq, A_in, B_in, C_in, D_in = params
           # Rate equations
           # should actually be rate = [k_1*x[1], k_2*x[2]*x[2], k_3*x[3], k_4*x[2]], as per @LutzL's comment
           rate = [k_1*x[1], k_2*x[2], k_3*x[3], k_4*x[2]]

           dx[1] = -rate[1] + q_in/V_liq*(A_in - x[1])
           dx[2] = 2*rate[1] - 2*rate[2] + 2*rate[3] - rate[4] + q_in/V_liq*(B_in - x[2])
           dx[3] = rate[2] - rate[3] + q_in/V_liq*(C_in - x[3])
           dx[4] = rate[4] + q_in/V_liq*(D_in - x[4])
       end
```

That works with both `Rosenbrock23` and `Rodas4`.

Alternatively, you can turn off AD with `Rosenbrock23(autodiff=false)` (which, I think, will use finite differences instead), or supply a Jacobian.

Comment: It's worth noting too that turning off autodiff, like `Rosenbrock23(autodiff=false)`, will work as well. Or supplying a Jacobian function.

Comment: Small error in your answer, since the fourth rate is actually `k_4*x[2]`, not `k_4*x[4]`, and the second rate should be, as pointed out by @LutzL, `k_2*x[2]*x[2]`. So the overall expression reads `rate = [k_1*x[1], k_2*x[2]*x[2], k_3*x[3], k_4*x[2]]`. Now, autodiff works!

Comment: I have two more issues: First, I would like to include `rate` as part of the solution object, so it can be viewed same as `u` and `t`. Is this possible somehow?
Second, when I use `ParameterizedFunctions.jl`, autodiff does not work either, but the error message is different. I should probably post a new question for the second issue and reference this one.

Comment: Yes, please do ask a new question.

Comment: Done, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54438451/4027729).
How about Issue #1? Is it possible to store intermediate variables (other than `u` and `t`) in the `sol` object? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe by using the [integrator interface](http://docs.juliadiffeq.org/stable/basics/integrator.html#Integrator-Interface-1), and maintaining a separate array. I'm actually the wrong person to ask that, though, never having used the package. But it might be a question worth asking here as well, or on Discourse.