# How to get Rosenbrock23 to work with ODE in ParameterizedFunctions.jl DSL?

Tags: julia, dsl, ode, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

Further to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422068/how-to-fix-typeerror-in-setindex-in-differentialequations-jl/54423008), I have the same model implemented in `ParameterizedFunctions.jl` DSL. The following MWE works:

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots

# Modeling a consecutive / parallel reaction in a CSTR
# A --> 2B --> C, C --> 2B, B --> D
# PETERSEN-Matrix
#   No.     A       B       C       D       Rate
#   1      -1       2                       k1*A
#   2              -2       1               k2*B*B
#   3               2      -1               k3*C
#   4              -1               1       k4*B

fpr! = @ode_def ConsecutiveParallelReaction begin
    dA = -k_1*A + q_in/V_liq*(A_in - A)
    dB = 2*k_1*A - 2*k_2*B*B + 2*k_3*C - k_4*B + q_in/V_liq*(B_in - B)
    dC = k_2*B*B - k_3*C + q_in/V_liq*(C_in - C)
    dD = k_4*B + q_in/V_liq*(D_in - D)
end k_1 k_2 k_3 k_4 q_in V_liq A_in B_in C_in D_in

u0 = [1.5, 0.1, 0, 0]
params = [1.0, 1.5, 0.75, 0.15, 3, 15, 0.5, 0, 0, 0]
tspan = (0.0, 15.0)
prob = ODEProblem(fpr!, u0, tspan, params)
sol = solve(prob)
plot(sol)
```

However, with `sol = solve(prob, Rosenbrock23())` (and even with `autodiff=false`), the following error occurs:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,1} to an object of type Float64
```

I suppose it is a similar issue like the abovementioned, but since I have not explicitly defined any `Float64` vectors here and `autodiff=false` does not eliminate the error, I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Are you sure you ran this in a new Julia session? If this was a new Julia session, make sure your packages are updated and you're running v1.0+.

Comment: Silly me, it's working now as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it seems like this actually works.

Comment: It used to; when I tried running it today (Julia 1.1.1 on Linux), I got: `ERROR: LoadError: type ConsecutiveParallelReaction has no field Wfact
Stacktrace:
 [1] getproperty(::Any, ::Symbol) at ./sysimg.jl:18`
Has anything changed in `DifferentialEquations.jl` which makes this code fail? 